# A simple question regarding for loops on a concrete example

Tags: python, for-loop

The program I got to do code in a Python-learning book is as follows :

```
VOWELS = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y')
pigLatin = [] # A list of the words in Pig Latin.
for word in message.split():
    # Separate the non-letters at the start of this word:
    prefixNonLetters = ''
    while len(word) > 0 and not word[0].isalpha():
        prefixNonLetters += word[0]
        word = word[1:]
    if len(word) == 0:
        pigLatin.append(prefixNonLetters)
        continue

    # Separate the non-letters at the end of this word:
    suffixNonLetters = ''
    while not word[-1].isalpha():
        suffixNonLetters += word[-1]
        word = word[:-1]

    # Remember if the word was in uppercase or title case.
    wasUpper = word.isupper()
    wasTitle = word.istitle()

    word = word.lower() # Make the word lowercase for translation.

    # Separate the consonants at the start of this word:
    prefixConsonants = ''
    while len(word) > 0 and not word[0] in VOWELS:
        prefixConsonants += word[0]
        word = word[1:]

    # Add the Pig Latin ending to the word:
    if prefixConsonants != '':
        word += prefixConsonants + 'ay'
    else:
        word += 'yay'

    # Set the word back to uppercase or title case:
    if wasUpper:
        word = word.upper()
    if wasTitle:
        word = word.title()

    # Add the non-letters back to the start or end of the word.
    pigLatin.append(prefixNonLetters + word + suffixNonLetters)

# Join all the words back together into a single string:
print(' '.join(pigLatin))
```

So basically, at the end of each iteration, I add a full word to the pigLatin list, including the transformed word itself and non-letter suffix and prefix ( if existent ).

However, it is a bit confusing to me because it challenges the way I thought about for-loops before this occasion. I thought the content of variables like prefixNonLetters or prefixConsonants in this instance, should stay in each iteration. But if it does, it messes up all the words succeeding the first one 
( they're gonna be too long with parts of previous words ).

So, my question is as follows: Does each iteration in a for loop empty the variables inside of it? This seems rather peculiar to me and definitely not aligned with the way I viewed for loops beforehand, but this seems to be the case because the program written like this does work properly...

Thank you in advance and sorry if the question I'm asking is too basic for some of you; I'm just a novice after all.

Comment: `prefixNonLetters ` and `prefixConsonants` are set to be equal to the empty string in each iteration, so are "cleared" that way.

Comment: So basically, variables inside for loops change with each iteration only if they contain an 'i' ( 'word' in this case ), and even then they're basically refreshed but soon acquire different values because of different values of the 'i' assigned to it ?

Comment: Yes, your `for` loop is assigning a new value to the `word` variable each iteration. All other variables will stay the same unless you change them.

Answer (score 0):

No. Variables are not "cleared" in each iteration unless you change them manually which you do. I will try to explain on a snippet of your code:

```
# Separate the consonants at the start of this word:
prefixConsonants = ''
```

The variable `prefixConsonants` holds now an empty string. If it was a first iteration it was just created in this scope. If it was subsequent iteration it was "cleared" i.e. the string it was holding before is replaced with an empty string.

```
while len(word) > 0 and not word[0] in VOWELS:
    prefixConsonants += word[0]
    word = word[1:]
```

In the end of this loop the variable `prefixConsonants` is filled with characters from `word` or it is still empty if the condition `len(word) > 0 and not word[0] in VOWELS` is false from the very beginning.
Whatever string is `prefixConsonants` holding will be there until the interpreter executes again the line `prefixConsonants = ''`.

Comment: What about the suffixNonLetters parts of the program ? If let's say, the word was 'why!?', the '?' would be added to the variable first, and only then the '!'. That means the word won't look as it should in the end, because ? and only then ! would be added at the end of it.

Comment: That is correct. The proper line should be probably `suffixNonLetters = word[-1]+suffixNonLetters ` instead of `suffixNonLetters += word[-1]`

Comment: Another question : why does the code require the word to be over 0 characters to meet the requirement for the execution of the prefixNonLetters and prefixConsonants blocks, but it isn't the case for the SuffixNonLetters one ?

Comment: that is already being checked by `if len(word) == 0:
        pigLatin.append(prefixNonLetters)
        continue`